# Given $f(x,y)=3:$ $ 0<x<1$, $0<y <x^2$ integrate $f$ w.r.t. $x$

Tags: integration

I'm not sure of to find the correct bounds $x_0, x_1$ for the integral $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}f(x,y)dx$. I think $x_0=0$ and $x_1=1$, but than I have not included the other inequality.

I'm trying to find the marginal distribution of $Y$. $f$ is a joint PDF for $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find $f_Y$ then you need to calculate :

$f_Y(y) = \int_{\Bbb R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$.

Now, if $y \notin [0,1]$ then $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0 \forall x$ hence $f_Y(y)=0$.

Otherwise, if $y\in [0,1]$ we need to find the bounds of this integral.

So we have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) =3 \iff x\in (0,1) y\in (0,x^2)$

So we get that $0<y<x^2$ so $x>\sqrt{y}$

Thus ,

$f_Y(y) = \int_{\Bbb R} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=\int_{\sqrt{y}}^13dx = 3(1-\sqrt{y})$.

Comment: But I have only to find the marginal distribution of $Y$. $f$ is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. This is why I think I need to integrate $f$ w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: i see , you didn't write it in your question, so i will edit my answer..

Comment: Oh, I can see that. I forgot, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Alright, thanks. But the correct answer should be $f_Y(y)=\int_{\sqrt{y}}^1f(x,y)dx$. My problem is that I do not know how the correct bounds are $\sqrt y$ to $1$ and not $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @Xenusi i had an error, fixed it right now

Comment: @Xenusi see my answer now and tell me if there is any question

Comment: My problem is that I can't figure out why the correct bounds are $\sqrt y$ and $1$. When I see the problem, I see the inequality $0 < x < 1$. SO I think that in order to "integrate $x$ out" I have to integrate over with the bounds $0$ to $1$. But I guess, if I do this I do not include the other inequality which also have some information about $x$. right ?

Comment: you want to find the bounds of $x$ given $y$ (remember that when calculating $f_Y(y)$ you can think of $y$ as fixed)

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Thanks.